# how to defer executing argument in defer function

Tags: go, defer-keyword

`defer` in `go` schedules a function call to be run after the function completes.
So `1st` print function `fmt.Println("a ", Even())` is defered. But as argument is executed when defer is called, `Even()` function is called immediately.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func MakeEvenNumber() func() int {
    num :=0
    return func() (ret int) {
        ret = num
        num = num + 2
        return ret
    }
}

func main() {

    Even := MakeEvenNumber()

    defer fmt.Println("a ", Even())

    fmt.Println("b ", Even())
    fmt.Println("c ", Even())
    fmt.Println("d ", Even())
}
```

Output:

```
b  2
c  4
d  6
a  0
```

This is happened in defer. I just want to know any way to stop executing argument in defer function?

like in this case, output will be:

```
b 0
c 2
d 4
a 6
```

`defer fmt.Println("a ", **Even()**)` this `Even()` function will be executed along with `Println`.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap the `fmt.Println` call in another function (an anonymous function, in this case), the evaluation of `Even()` will happen after the other calls to `Even` have completed:

```
func main() {
    Even := MakeEvenNumber()

    defer func() {
      fmt.Println("a ", Even())
    }()

    fmt.Println("b ", Even())
    fmt.Println("c ", Even())
    fmt.Println("d ", Even())
}
```